# How can i prevent a CSS body from affecting a specific Div?

Tags: html, css

I recently started using Filegator as a file manager for my website, and in my quest of integrating it in my website's design i added my website's header to it.

My problem is that a couple parts of my header seem to be affected by some css rules from Filegator, more specifically some kind of margin/height not being respected.
The part of the header in question is a simple div with the following css :

```
#account {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #3F3F3F;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

After some research i noticed that i comes from a css file name foundation.css and that, inside, if i delete this particular line of code my header goes back to normal :

```
body
{
    background: white;
    color: #222222;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Thing is that line of code is essential for the file manager, so i tried adding the famous :not() like this :

```
  body:not(#account)
{
    background: white;
    color: #222222;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

But `body:not()` did not change anything.

It gets even worse if i write it with a space between body and `:not()`

Does anyone have suggestions to help me with this ?
Any help would be really appreciated

Thanks

-Apatik

Comment: Please provide a testcase of the problem. Your approach won't work because `body` already does not select your `div` element. It could be that your element inherits some properties from `body`. Or it could be that your element has e.g. an invisible background, and thus the background of the `body` is shown.

Comment: `body:not(#account)` – that would match the `body` element, if that element does not have the id `account` – since you are talking about a “header”, I suppose that is a different element than `body` …? Pretty unclear what you’re asking here – you should at least add some HTML code to make the problem reproducible ([mcve]), and also be clear about what the actual problem is – _“a couple parts of my header seem to be affected by some css rules from Filegator, more specifically some kind of margin/height not being respected”_ is not very meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, and the feedback. My header is indeed in the body. It's composed of 3 differents main divs : top-left menu, top-right menu, and the logo. My problems concerns mainly the top-left menu (div named account which contains "welcome $username") and the logo. Instead of being at a 10px margin from the top of the page, they appear at 20-25px from the top of the page because of the line of code mentionned in my post. Hope it's a bit better with theses informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only rule that you don't override seems line-height, so you could try to explictly set or unset this in you 'account.

```
#account{
  ...
 line-height:0; 
}
```

Comment: Hello ! thanks for your answer, i was indeed doing this exact thing and it worked, so your answer is correct :) Although it seems that 'position' is also being redifined by the body css of foundation.css. So i tried doing the same thing, and adding the rule position:static everywhere it wasn't specified on my css, but it didn't do the trick. So i specified it in my own body css temporarly. But it's already way better visually. Thanks !